# Error reading renderscript file

Tags: android, renderscript

Just new to play around renderscript. I am able to run HelloCompute sample in the android SDK sample but fail to import renderscript to my own project by

1.create "sample.rs', keep the java_package_name to my project

2.import renderscript and new a "ScriptC_sample"

but eclipse keep telling me `"error: error reading 'D:\android\Project\XXXXX\src\com\XXX\gltexture\sample.rs'"`

and I can't find the "ScriptC_sample.java" anywhere.

Have I miss anything configuration of these? why the Script_sample.java didn't complied automatically?

FYI: I have eclipse, android sdk tools 22.6.3, android platform tools 19.0.1 and I set both of these projects API 19 android 4.4.2

Thanks!

Comment: What is gltexture in the path above? Is it part of the package name? Look at where the .rs file is in the Sample projects to know where you should be placing your .rs file. I think for eclipse it is with the .java source files, but under Android Studio, there is now a separate subdirectory (but it isn't gltexture).

Comment: Hi , gltexture is just part of my package name. I am using eclipse and place .rs file with the .java source file exactly the same as the sample project.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicRenderScript/project.html, perhaps you do need an rs/ dir under src/ to place your .rs files. Can you try that out?

Comment: I just try this and it's not working... I find something else interesting. I just new a blank project and put .rs file in the java source folder. It works! and build the ScriptC_XXX.java immediately in the gen folder!!! Something must be wrong with my project settings! I gonna carefully check them out.